# Extract subset of postgis data to sqlite using SQL query

Tags: postgis, sql, sqlite

I have a large vector mapping dataset held in postgis.  This consists of about 20 individual tables in a single schema.  I want to extract a subset of each of these tables into a standalone sqlite database using ogr2ogr.  This code from the [postgis website](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/SpatiaLite) does this and this works ok for transferring the entirety of each table:

```
    ogr2ogr --config PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES --config PG_SKIP_VIEWS YES -f "SQLite" mydb.sqlite -progress PG:"dbname='mydb' \
  active_schema=myschema schemas=myschema host='localhost' port='5432' user='myuser' password='mypass' " -lco LAUNDER=yes \
  -dsco SPATIALITE=yes -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=yes -gt 65536
```

However, I would like to only export a subset of each table based on an field called 'Tile_Name'.

I assume I can use the keyword '-clipdstwhere' to extract data based on an attribute, for example where the 'Tile_Name' field is NT, NY, or NZ?

In a standard definition query I would use `Tile_Name IN (NT, NY, NZ)`, but this obviously isn't the correct syntax as I get the error "ERROR 1: No field definitions found for 'IN', is it a table?".

There are also options for clipping the data by a boundary or bounding box - might this be an easier way?

Comment: You have many tables in PostGIS and you want to export them all together? And all the tables have an attribute Tile_Name?

Comment: Hi - yes.  I have about 20 tables, all of which I want to dump into a sqlite database - that is what the original ogr2ogr code does.  All the tables have the 'Tile_Name' field which I'd like to use to extract a subset of each table.

I've updated the question slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: IN is for sure supported in `-sql "select * from table_1 where Tile_Name in ('NT', 'NY', 'NZ')"` but for using that you must convert one table at a time and append the result into the same SpatiaLite db. I would test the query with one table and write a script or batch file that converts the tables one by one. There is not much to edit - the table name, perhaps -nln for defining the name of the output table, and after the first conversion when the db already axists, to inclule -append.